# How to use computed properties in vue-class for v-model?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I wanna use v-model for vuedraggable plugin with vuex, but i don't know how set computed property like below not in `@Component` decorator. Have another solutions for that?

```
computed: {
  myList: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.Goal.goalData.steps
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.dispatch('sortList', {id: this.$store.state.Goal.goalId, list:value})
    }
  }
}

<draggable v-model='myList'></draggable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do it this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="computedMsg">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component({
  props: {
    propMessage: String
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {

  // computed
  get computedMsg () {
    return state.val
  }

  set computedMsg (val) {
    return store.commit("changeVal", val)
  }
}
</script>
```

Please remember that you'll need to tailor the code above to fit your specific application.